# What is the format of the TLS extension field?

Tags: tls

In the TLS 1.2 protocol, the client may send extensions. My question is: what is the format of this field? is it a list?

In TLS 1.2 `client hello`, the standard says:

> extensions
>         Clients MAY request extended functionality from servers by sending
>         data in the extensions field.  The actual "Extension" format is
>         defined in Section 7.4.1.4.

At the `server hello`, the standard explicitly says it is a list. But I am not sure if this implies that the client also sends the extensions as a list:

> extensions A list of extensions.  Note that only extensions offered by
>   the client can appear in the server's list.

I assume the same format is used in tLS 1.3 as well.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with cryptography and probably belongs next door on security.SX.

Comment: It is actually called a variable length vector and the syntax is described in section 4.3. The maximum number of octets has implications to the runtime format, because it demands a length tag of uint16 (2 octets) before the actual concatenation of encoded extensions (and each encoded extension gives its own length representation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 7.4.1.2 of RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2) defines the following `ClientHello`:

> ```
>   struct {
>       ProtocolVersion client_version;
>       Random random;
>       SessionID session_id;
>       CipherSuite cipher_suites<2..2^16-2>;
>       CompressionMethod compression_methods<1..2^8-1>;
>       select (extensions_present) {
>           case false:
>               struct {};
>           case true:
>               Extension extensions<0..2^16-1>;
>       };
>   } ClientHello;
> ```

As you can see, you can add up to $2^{16}=65536$ *bytes* of extensions to your client hello in a list format as per [section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-4.3).

Comment: That's 65536 _-1 bytes of_ extensions. Each extension must be at least 4 bytes, and most actually-used extensions are more, so the number of extensions can't be more than a few thousand, and in practice is never more than a dozen or two.

Comment: @SEJPM Thanks a lot for your helpful answers. Two more question about this please. Correct me if I'm wrong. 1) The following notation in the standard `<...>` always means a list format?? 2) That means the extensions field is a list of lists. Reference to the Extension struct in [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.4), I get that the Hellos extension field is a list of lists (each extension is represented by a list).

Comment: @user6875880 yes, `<...>` always denotes a variable-length list format in RFC 5246. And yes the Extension struct is a header (the `ExtensionType`) with up to $2^16$ bytes worth of data. And yes these extensions are organized as a list themselves.

Comment: @SEJPM Sorry but just recognised that, struct is not a list. It is a datatype in itself, isn't it? I'm confused in a message sequence diagram, say a client hello with multiple extensions including key_share extension as in TLS 1.3. Should it by like: `client_hello(.., [..,[k_1,k_2],..], ..)` or just: `client_hello(.., [k_1,k_2], ..)` ?? do you see the difference? either the list of key shares inside the client_hello directly, or inside a list (the Extension parameter). I'm confused.

Comment: @user6875880 If the `key_shares` is an extension that defines its own list-format (or re-uses the TLS one), the _extension_ would be an entry in the outer list (marking the following bytes / entries as `key_share` entries) and then there would be an inner list of `key_share`s, so in total something like `client_hello(...,[...,{key_shares,[k_1,k_2]},...],...)`